# Html href not showing full path in blazor server

Tags: css, blazor

I would like to hide my div after clicking on an  tag using only CSS!

In HTML, it works as expected and shows the full path: "https://localhost:7078/panel/Invoicetest#start-menu-modal".

However, in Blazor, the URL becomes: "https://localhost:7078/#start-menu-modal".

Even if I add /panel/invoicetest, it's not working. Any suggestions?

HTML:

```
<a href="#start-menu-modal" id="start-menu"><i class="fab fa-windows"></i></a>
```

CSS:

```
#start-menu-modal {
    background: #005a9e;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 43px;
    height: 600px;
    color: white;
    visibility: hidden;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 50px 250px 400px;
    cursor: default;
}

    #start-menu-modal:target {
        visibility: visible !important;
        animation-name: open;
        animation-duration: 0.1s;
        transition: 0.1s;
    }
@keyframes open {
    0% {
        height: 550px;
        opacity: 0.5;
    }

    100% {
        height: 600px;
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

I would like to show my div with only css.

Answer (score 0):

Blazor uses "root relative" routing, so any anchor tags need the relative url and the simplest way to always get that correct is to do this

```html
@inject NavigationManager Nav

<a href=@(Nav.ToBaseRelativePath($"{Nav.Uri}#start-menu-modal"))
 target="_top"
 id="start-menu">
 <i class="fab fa-windows"></i>
</a>
```

Note that `target="_top"` was needed in early Blazor - depending on what version you are on, you may or may not need it now.